# How to display associated models in separate Ext grids?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4

I have two associated models, User and Order. A User has many Orders.

```
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'name'
    ],

    hasMany: {model: 'Order', name: 'orders'},

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define("Order", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'total'
    ],

    belongsTo: 'User'
});
```

I'd like to display all of the Users in one grid panel, and all of the orders in another grid. I know how to show all of the Users in a grid, I simply define a store with the User model. But I'm a bit lost as to how to show all of the orders in a separate grid. Do I have to define a separate store? What proxy do I use? Anyone have insight? Basically, I just need a conceptual understanding.

Comment: do you want to show the orders according to a selected user or just show all orders?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking for is a fairly common use case. Unfortunately ExtJs is not yet able to cope with this out of the box, simply as currently each grid is bound to a store, but your orders store is created on the fly every time you access it through its user association.

The good news is that you have various ways to achieve this. The best one I can think of is that every time the user clicks on a user row, you get your orders store (`user.orders()`). Then you can [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) your grid with this new store.

Comment: Do I simply pass user.orders() into reconfigure()? But that method accepts a store as an argument? How does it work?

Comment: Give it a go - it should work. And yes, `user.orders()` returns a store.

Comment: Cool. It works. But how come I can't just specify it as the Grid's `store` property when I create the grid? At the moment I have to create an empty grid (no store), and then call `grid.reconfigure(user.orders())`. Seem hacky.

Comment: The thing is that the `users.orders()` store is only being created first time you access it. Also, for each user `users.orders()` will return a different store.

Answer (score 0):

Usually each Grid needs its own Store. Showing all orders will work the same way as showing all users, just change the Store ID and it should be okay.